# python re: r'\b \$ \d+ \b' won't match 'aug 12, 2010 abc $123'

Tags: python, regex

so i'm just making a script to collect $ values from a transaction log type file

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    match = re.match( r'\b \$ (\d+) \b', line)
    if match is not None:
            for value in match.groups():
                    print value
```

right now I'm just trying to print those values
it would match a line containing $12323 but not when there are other things in the line
From what I read it should work, but looks like I could be missing something

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`re.match`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.RegexObject.match):

> If zero or more characters **at the beginning of string** match this regular expression, return a corresponding MatchObject instance. Return None if the string does not match the pattern; note that this is different from a zero-length match.

What your are looking for is either [`re.search`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.RegexObject.search) or [`re.findall`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.RegexObject.findall):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import re
s = 'aug 12, 2010 abc $123'

print re.findall(r'\$(\d+)', s)
# => ['123']

print re.search(r'\$(\d+)', s).group()
# => $123

print re.search(r'\$(\d+)', s).group(1)
# => 123
```

Answer (score 3):

By having a space between `\$` and `(\d+)`, the regex expects a space in your string between them. Is there such a space?

Comment: spaces are only ignored in multiline string?

Comment: @lanzelloth: spaces are only ignored if you use the `re.VERBOSE` (or `re.X`) modifier.  Multiline has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

I am not so clear what is accepted for you but from statement

> a line containing $12323 but not when there are other things in the line

I would get that

> 'aug 12, 2010 abc $123'

Is not supposed to match as it has other text befor the amount.

If you want to match amount at end of the line here is the customary anti-regexp answer (even I am not against of using them in easy cases):

```
loglines = ['aug 12, 2010 abc $123', " $1 ", "a $1 amount", "exactly $1 - no less"]

# match $amount at end of line without other text after
for line in loglines:
    if '$' in line:
        _,_, amount = line.rpartition('$')
        try:
            amount = float(amount)
        except:
            pass
        else:
            print "$%.2f" % amount
```

Answer (score 0):

Others have already pointed out some shortcomings of your regex (especially the mandatory spaces and `re.match` vs. `re.search`).

There is another thing, though: `\b` word anchors match *between* alphanumeric and non-alphanumeric characters. In other words, `\b \$` will fail (even when doing a search instead of a match operation) unless the string has some alphanumeric characters before the space.

Example (admittedly contrived) to work with your regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> test = [" $1 ", "a $1 amount", "exactly $1 - no less"]
>>> for string in test:
...     print(re.search(r"\b \$\d+ \b", string))
...
None
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x0000000001DD4370>
None
```